# Can Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on 1GB RAM and 1GHZ Processor?? Please Answer

Tags: system-installation, system-requirements

I want instal Ubuntu on my notebook,
Will Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.3 LTS work perfectly on;

AMD C-60 1GHz processor
1 GB RAM
30 GB HDD

I know the recommendation system requirements

I just want to know Ubuntu will work properly or not with this spech??
Please Answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you will not have much of performance left for applications and you may quickly run out of RAM if you will try to run any hardware-expensive app. Also, you may assign a bit of disk as SWAP, but it will be REALLY slow then

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu needs more CPU horsepower and more RAM to work well. Probably also a better graphics card (but you did not tell us about that).

I would recommend Lubuntu, an Ubuntu community flavour with an ultra-light desktop environment and some lighter application programs. I would recommend Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS,

[cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/16.04.1/release/lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/16.04.1/release/lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso)

with the following md5sum

```
72a400913ba0ed59b88c42e5aab629e9 *lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
```